# pandas: generate and plot average

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
In [61]: df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4), index=['art','mcf','mesa'],
                        columns=['pol1','pol2','pol3','pol4'])

In [62]: df
Out[62]: 
          pol1      pol2      pol3      pol4
art   0.661592  0.479202  0.700451  0.345085
mcf   0.235517  0.665981  0.778774  0.610344
mesa  0.838396  0.035648  0.424047  0.866920
```

and I want to generate a row with the average for the policies across benchmarks and then plot it.

Currently, the way I do this is:

```
df = df.T
df['average'] = df.apply(average, axis=1)
df = df.T
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Is there an elegant way to avoid the double transposition?

I tried:

```
df.append(DataFrame(df.apply(average)).T)
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

This will append the correct values but does not update the index properly and the graph is messed up.

A clarification. The result of the code with the double transposition is this: [image] 
This is what I want. To show both the benchmarks and the average of the policies, not just the average. I was just curious if I can do it better.

Note that the legend is usually messed up. For a fix:

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.legend(patches, list(df.columns), loc='best')
```

Comment: Why do you have your data structured in this way?  It's always a bit suspicious when your columns have numbers and your rows have names.  It seems like it would make more sense to just keep the table in the transposed format.  Then if you want to plot it the other way you can just do `d.T.plot()`.

Comment: Well, in computer architecture this type of graph is probably what you will find it 99% of the all research papers. The height of the bars represents either raw ipc (instructions per cycle) or normalized performance.

Comment: Sure, but I'm just pointing out that you can store the data in the transposed form if it makes more sense, and only *plot* it in other orientation (by plotting `df.T` instead of `df`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply use the instance method `mean` of the `DataFrame` and than plot the results. There is no need for transposition.

```
In [14]: df.mean()
Out[14]: 
pol1    0.578502
pol2    0.393610
pol3    0.634424
pol4    0.607450

In [15]: df.mean().plot(kind='bar')
Out[15]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x4a327d0>
```

[image: policies.png]

### Update

If you want to plot the bars of all columns and the mean you can `append` the mean:

```
In [95]: average = df.mean()

In [96]: average.name = 'average'

In [97]: df = df.append(average)

In [98]: df
Out[98]: 
             pol1      pol2      pol3      pol4
art      0.661592  0.479202  0.700451  0.345085
mcf      0.235517  0.665981  0.778774  0.610344
mesa     0.838396  0.035648  0.424047  0.866920
average  0.578502  0.393610  0.634424  0.607450

In [99]: df.plot(kind='bar')
Out[99]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x52f4390>
```

[image: second plot]

If your layout doesn't fit in to the subplot [`tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html#tight-layout-guide) will adjust the matplotlib parameters.

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I wanted. Plus, the tight_layout tip is one to remember, had no clue about it.